# PHP get response headers

Tags: php

It seems like I can't find this information 'on the line', which is kind of surprising. How can I grab the currently set **response** headers by php so far?

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

echo headers("Content-Type"); // 'image/jpeg'
```

Comment: @ling.s absolutely agree. I just didn't think of searching for 'response headers', I just did 'php set headers' instead. How silly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php function "[headers_list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php)" is what you probably need.

> headers_list — Returns a list of response headers sent (or ready to
>   send)

You can then use the function "[headers_sent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)" to check if the headers have been sent.

> headers_sent — Checks if or where headers have been sent

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Correct answer added below.

**Request Headers**

Did a quick search and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) came up.

Example from the php page:

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

The other method is `getallheaders()`, which runs `apache_request_headers();` anyway. So why not stick with the main one :)

**Response Headers**

Found [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) on php.net.

Hopefully this is more helpful to you.

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

Comment: Request headers are not response headers. The question is asking about response headers.

Comment: Yeah I also found this but I'm talking about response headers

Comment: Ah, my bad. Its early morning here....forgive me haha! I shall see if i can think of anything related to response headers.

Comment: I believe I have found the correct answer which gets all of the headers sent by the server. I have added it as a link above.

Comment: I'm trying to get the headers in the currently running script. See zaf's answer. +rep for the effort though, thanks!

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks! I tried haha! Well, hopefully someone finds the answer I have given useful somewhere :)